# How can I fix errors created when using a non-exact decimal in CSS?

Tags: css, responsive-design

I've used the 'target / context = result' trick on a site I'm developing, but I've run into a fairly large issue: the equation returns a percent so long, I can't find a calculator to complete the equation without rounding. As you can see below, I've set the height to a percent instead of auto, as if the value is auto, it will chop of the bottom part of the div, which I need. So, I've set it to the nearest rounded decimal - looks fine at first, then resize and it becomes larger/smaller than I need it to be. For reference for what it should look like, it should be the same height as image next to it. I can't provide the image for copyright reasons, but the image size is 800 by 440 pixels. Just apply the second rule to it. Thanks.

```
#comment-1 {
    width: 6.25%;
    height: 30.09781790820166%;
    padding: 20px;
    float: left;
    color: #FFF;
    background-color: #CC521D;
    font-family: "Lato", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 125%;
}

#image-1 {
    width: 31.25%;
    height: auto;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 20px; 
}
```

EDIT: Just noticed, I forget to provide the context: the height is 1329px and the width is 2560px.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Height percent will be based on parent element **width** if parent element height was not set! That means you need another approach, one of the solutions would be: let your image container be `relative`, with padding left 6.25%, than your comment would be `absolute` with `left, top, bottom: 0` (width can be calculated as 6.25/31.25*100). That way the image height would control comment height.

```
<style type="text/css">
    .comment_and_image {
        position: relative;
        width: 31.25%;
        padding-left: 6.25%;
        float: left;
    }
    .comment {
        width: 20%; /* 6.25/31.25*100 */
        position: absolute;
        left: 0;
        top: 0;
        bottom: 0;
    }
    .image {
        height: auto;
        width: 100%;
    }
</style>

<div class="comment_and_image">
    <div class="comment">text</div>
    <img class="image" src="path_to_image.jpg" alt="Image" />
</div>
```

Comment: I haven't been able to test this as I've been on my iPad, but I have looked it over - where is the height of the comment div being set?

Comment: this way it completely depends on image height.

Answer (score 0):

I've used skobaljic's answer, just a modified version. I've set the top and bottom rules to 0, as he said, but instead of leaving left at 0, I set the margin-left to 101.875, as it is the width of the image plus 15 pixels, exactly what I needed.